# Add unique if constraints does not exist check in one line?

Tags: postgresql

I am autogenerated SQL queries based on some condition of the autogenerated resulted into this query

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_attribute
               WHERE  attrelid = 'public.registration'::regclass  -- table name here 
               AND    attname = 'price'    -- column name here
               AND    NOT attisdropped
              ) THEN

        ALTER TABLE public.registration 
        ADD COLUMN price text UNIQUE NULL;
ELSE
        ALTER TABLE public.registration
        ALTER COLUMN  price TYPE  text,
        ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS registration_price_key UNIQUE (price);
END IF;
END
$$
```

So the table is is already there by if the column is not there it will be added and a unique constraint will be added to that column problem if it does not already exist

I get that an syntax error on this line `near NOT

```
        ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS registration_price_key UNIQUE (price);
```

but why?

Comment: I think there should be no comma before the `ADD`

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)  there is no `IF NOT EXISTS` option when adding a constraint

Comment: So there is no way around this?

Comment: I ended dropping the constraint if it existed and then adding it